# Marshal.PtrToStructure equivalent in JNA

Tags: java, jna

What is the equivalent of .NET's *Marshal.PtrToStructure* in JNA?

I am trying to write a Firefox password decrypter in Java and am looking at the C# equivalent, I have completed most of it but I'm stuck on this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Structure(Pointer)` constructor, e.g.

```
public class MyStructure extends Structure {
    public MyStructure(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }
}
```